# gnu date - how come last month isn't?

Tags: unix, gnu

I'm trying to use the date command to get the previous month. When I run it on the 31 of may, it returns may 1, I was expecting something in april. Is there better way to do this ?

```
> date --version
 date (GNU sh-utils) 2.0
Written by David MacKenzie.

Copyright (C) 1999 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
> date
Fri May 31 13:29:08 EDT 2013
> date --date='last month'
Wed May  1 13:29:15 EDT 2013
```

per comment from @fvu I tried this :

```
> date --date='first day last month'
Thu May  2 14:00:43 EDT 2013
> date --date='first day next month'
Tue Jul  2 14:00:52 EDT 2013
```

which didn't quite work.  this did though :

```
>date --date='last day last month'
Tue Apr 30 14:06:28 EDT 2013
```

guess I need the definition of month

Comment: May be related to [a comparable effect in php](http://derickrethans.nl/obtaining-the-next-month-in-php.html) as to my knowledge both use the same parsing code...

Comment: wow... Still true with `date (GNU coreutils) 5.97`. (You don't have a TZ variable set do you? ... At least it's consistent, `date --date 'Oct 31 2013 last month' returns Oct 1 2013`) Good luck!

Comment: "last month" is meant to be 30 days ago,  not the previous month, I believe. date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) -1 month"  is the info example given to detect the previous month because -1 month is the same as -30  days

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015187

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"last month" is meant to be 30 days ago, not the previous month, I believe.

```
date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) -1 month"
```

is the info example given to detect the previous month because -1 month is the same as -30 days