# How does 'date -d' parse dates?

Tags: unix, date

Just now ("Sun Jun  9 17:19:24 MDT 2013"), I ran this command:

```
> date -d "first Sunday next month" 
Tue Jul  9 00:00:00 MDT 2013
```

which is neither a Sunday, and isn't even the first Tuesday of next month:

- How is date -d interpreting my input?
- Is there a verbose option to date (or even "date -d") that shows 
  how my input is interpreted? It's not -v, and "man date" doesn't 
  show a verbose option.
- I realize there's probably some library handling "date -d". Where 
  can I find that library and its documentation, limitations, etc?
- I realize no program can handle every possible format, but it's 
  unnerving to see "date -d" give the wrong answer. I'd have much 
  preferred "date: can not parse 'first Sunday next month'" to the 
  wrong answer.

EDIT: running this on fedora 11 core:

```
> date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 7.2
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: You did not mention where you are running this command.

Comment: This functionality is not POSIX-defined. It certainly is not the same from implementation to implementation, so there is no canonical answer available to give.

Comment: It seems to be treating the "next Sunday" part as an offset from today's date next month. "First Monday" gives (for me) July 10, "First Tuesday" give July 11, etc.

Comment: (you mean "next month", not "next Sunday" right?)

Comment: -d, --date=STRING
              display time described by STRING, not `now'

, it gave  Jul 16 for me , strangs

Comment: @CharlesDuffy totally agree , +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - How is date -d interpreting my input?

Via [this Bison grammar](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/parse-datetime.y) that's part of [Gnulib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/), on which `date` (and indeed much of the coreutils package) depends. My days of writing grammars are long gone, but the relative date/time parsing "fun" seems to start around [line 892](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/parse-datetime.y#n892).

> - Is there a verbose option to date (or even "date -d") that shows how my input is interpreted?

The current version of GNU date as I write this (v8.28) *does* have a debug mode:

```
$ date --debug -d "first Sunday next month"
date: parsed day part: next/first Sun (day ordinal=1 number=0)
date: parsed relative part: +1 month(s)
date: input timezone: system default
date: warning: using midnight as starting time: 00:00:00
date: new start date: 'next/first Sun' is '(Y-M-D) 2019-02-03 00:00:00'
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2019-02-03 00:00:00'
date: warning: when adding relative months/years, it is recommended to specify the 15th of the months
date: after date adjustment (+0 years, +1 months, +0 days),
date:     new date/time = '(Y-M-D) 2019-03-03 00:00:00'
date: '(Y-M-D) 2019-03-03 00:00:00' = 1551542400 epoch-seconds
date: timezone: system default
date: final: 1551542400.000000000 (epoch-seconds)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2019-03-02 16:00:00 (UTC)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2019-03-03 00:00:00 (UTC+08)
Sun Mar  3 00:00:00 +08 2019
```

As you can see, it went left-to-right;
* "first Sunday" resolves forward to the first Sunday of Feb 2019 (2019-Feb-03), then
* "next month" adds one month (2019-Mar-03), which just happens to be a Sunday too, since it's not a leap year.

> - I realize there's probably some library handling "date -d". Where can I find that library and its documentation, limitations, etc?

Gnulib, as mentioned above. Also, the [Date input formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html) section of the coreutils manual is worth reading in detail.

> - I realize no program can handle every possible format, but it's unnerving to see "date -d" give the wrong answer. I'd have much preferred "date: can not parse 'first Sunday next month'" to the wrong answer.

I'm sure the authors of the `parse_datetime` routine would agree. Sadly, your date phrasing seems like it just happens to match some grouping of the existing grammar rules, so `date` dutifully does the necessary calculation...and comes up with the wrong answer.

Perhaps a polite bug report to the Gnulib bugs mailing list (bug-gnulib@gnu.org) might set some gears turning.

Oh, and you probably already figured it out, but `date -d "first Sunday"` gets you the right result...as long as you're past the current month's first Sunday. :)

Answer (score 1):

GNU date options :

-d, --date=string display time described by string, not now. It is a human readable format such as "next Thursday" or "1 month ago". A date string may contain items indicating calendar date, time of day, time zone, day of week, relative time, relative date, and numbers. This is also known as relative GNU date formats.[1] Here are a few examples of relative date:

```
date --date="1 days ago"
date --date="yesterday"
date --date='10 month ago'
date --date='2 hour ago'
date --date='Second Friday'
```

i bluntly copied this from the wiki.  : `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_(Unix)`

this date -d is stupid -- gave me 16th July as the next first sunday next month

```
Kaizen ~ $ date -d "first Sunday next month"
+ date -d 'first Sunday next month'
Tue Jul 16 00:00:00 IST 2013
```

it seems that the string has keywords that are anded and then results given.... Sunday + next month... after todays date ie 10th (in June) in the next month (July) is 16th of July.
if i did use Monday here instead of Sunday , i get 17th July as answer.

```
 Kaizen ~ $ date -d "next month monday"
 + date -d 'next month monday'
 Wed Jul 10 00:00:00 IST 2013
```

like wise if i use "next month monday" then it will go to the next month and look for monday from todays date ie 10th is the result.

does this help ?

Also it's super not portable and dosen't work alike on all servers ... dont know about you but I would stay away from it for programing purposes.

also there was a super user question of similar nature : `http://superuser.com/questions/572088/unix-date-command-not-working-for-few-servers` you can check that out too